# How do I write a compound if statement in Groovy?

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to write an `if` statement that tests two conditions in Groovy, but the language does not appear to support `&&` or `&`. I'd like to avoid using a nested `if` statement if possible for this. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, it does support those: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_logical_operators Show what you have, and what specifically you're getting stuck on.

Comment: i am making a script in groovy at katalon. there is am stucked with IF statement while passing a condition.I want to validate both username and password which have been dragged out of excel data. If both of them match my criteria then block should be executed.

Comment: Again, show what you have. A vague description of what you're trying to do isn't very helpful on its own. As shown by me and the answerer, Groovy does in fact support those operators.

Comment: "...but the language does not appear to support && or &" - That is definitely not the case.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown bro i want to pass two condition in the IF block. How can i do this

Comment: I assume, that this is a limitation of katalon-studio (removed the groovy tag)

Comment: "bro i want to pass two condition in the IF block. How can i do this" - You can do something like `if(a && b) { ... }` or `if(a < 100 && a > 0) { ... }`.  You can use as many conditions as you like... `if(a && b && c && d) { ... }`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes groove support the logical-and operator('&&') and bitwise-and operator('&').

```
class Example { 
 static void main(String[] args) { 
  // Initializing a local variable 
  int a = 2

  //Check for the boolean condition 
  if (a<100 && a>0) { 
     //If the condition is true print the following statement 
     println("The value is less than 100"); 
  } else { 
     //If the condition is false print the following statement 
     println("The value is greater than 100"); 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: isn't this java code?

Comment: no, this is groovy code [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/index.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/index.htm)
There is given the groovy editor you can **change code and check the result.**

Answer (score 2):

> but it is not supporting '&&' or '&'

That's incorrect. Both the logical AND (`&&`) and the bitwise and (`&`) work in groovy. See the list of operators in the [official documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html).